# Is there a way to convert timedelta to pandas freq string?

Tags: python, pandas, frequency, timedelta

You can do `pd.to_timedelta('30min')` to get a timedelta object of 30 minutes. Is there a similar way to go from a timedelta object to the freq string (like '30min', '1H', etc.)?

Comment: There's no "the" freq string, e.g. '30min' = '0.5H'. You could do something like `f'{pd.Timedelta("0.5h").total_seconds()/60}min'`.

Comment: Ah ofcourse, thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can create a pd.DateOffset and use its freqstr attribute:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
offset = to_offset(pd.Timedelta('30min'))
print(offset.freqstr)
# 30T
```